# When using for loop, to write looping PTransform in Apache Beam by Python SDK. All loops use the last value of a iterator

Tags: python, for-loop, apache-beam

The event of the title occurred. The example code is below.
Is this a bug, or is it written incorrectly?

```
import apache_beam as beam


def main():
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        p_f = (
                p
                | beam.Create([
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        ]))
        for i in range(3):
            p_f = (p_f
                   | f"{i}" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x + i)
                   )

        p_f | beam.Map(print)


main()
```

In the example code,
I expect [4, 5, 6, 7, 8] because adding 0+1+2=3.

But I got [7, 8, 9, 10]. All elements are added to 6.
That is looks like only using the last value in for-loop.
(2 is last value. loop times is 3.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a small mistake.

> But I got [7, 8, 9, 10].

[7, 8, 9, 10, 11] is correct.

Comment: This section is for answers. If you want to modify your question or add clarifying information, please edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I propose your code with some updates :

```py
def main():
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
            p_f = (
                    p
                    | beam.Create([
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5
            ]))

            p_f = (p_f
                   | "Map" >> beam.Map(self.add_ranges_to_value))

            p_f | beam.Map(print)

    def add_ranges_to_value(self, value:int) -> int:
        for i in range(3):
            value = value + i

        return value
```

I moved the `for loop` and incrementation logic inside the pure transformation in the `Beam` `Map` operation.

The result matches the expected : `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Comment: @Tomomasa have you tried my proposition ?